# Exponentially growing execution time in laravel queue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

## Explanation

I currently have a set of queues lined up to upload and handle large amounts of data. This setup is quite tedious because i have to check if the record already exists, and since I'm uploading on the far side of 10k records I have to cut down on the amount of records each queue has to handle.

I have setup one queue to handle the data and chunk it up into bits of 500 records each, I then pass these chunks onto it's own individual queue, which checks each record if it exists and then proceeds to upload it to the database.

I have setup a listener to check how long this exact process takes, and this is where the problem occurs.

Running `php artisan queue:listen --memory=1024 --timeout=100` in my CLI lets the first few queues take around 5-10 seconds. Then they exponentially start to increase in time.

```
This batch took: 29.013844013214 Seconds to process
This batch took: 28.680887937546 Seconds to process 
This batch took: 28.172641992569 Seconds to process 
This batch took: 27.722810983658 Seconds to process 
This batch took: 20.302350997925 Seconds to process
This batch took: 16.653347969055 Seconds to process 
This batch took: 16.353777885437 Seconds to process
This batch took: 15.923125982285 Seconds to process 
This batch took: 15.426895856857 Seconds to process
This batch took: 15.151268005371 Seconds to process
```

This can go on up until 100+ seconds, and then randomly resets down to 5-10 seconds again.

This is the code i use to handle the records.

```
       foreach ($data as $record) {
            $batch_id = $record['batch_id'];
            unset($record['batch_id']);
            if (is_null(Record::where($record)->first())) {
                $record['batch_id'] = $batch_id;
                $upload[] = $record;
            } else {
                $duplicatechunks++;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($upload)) {
            DB::table('records')->insert($upload);
        }
```

This code deletes the value `Batch_id` because it is unique and therefore I cannot use it in the search for existing records. The code also keeps track of the `$duplicatechunks` value which is just a way to know whether or not that record has been uploaded before. `$duplicatechunks` gets uploaded to a `$batch` I am keeping track of in this queue as well. At the beginning of the code it is set from `$duplicatechunks = $batch->chunks_duplicate` and then below the database insertion is `$batch->chunks_duplicate = $duplicatechunks` to save it.

## What i have tried so far

- I tried giving the process that handles inserting records more processing power, but that only works for a minute or so.
- I also tried editing the code from uploading each record individually to bulk uploading them. This sped up the general time from 19 seconds down to 5 per queue.

## Important

- Queue handler is database, using the built in laravel jobs table

Has anyone had similar issues with queues?

## Edit:

Since these records are not saved anywhere until the InsertRecords job executes and stores them in the database, could that have any impact on time these take to execute? Would it be wiser to store all the records temporarily in a different table, and then migrate them into the actual one later?

Answer (score 0):

Each queue has an `expire` time you can configure.  I don't know if this can be configured per job, but it can be configured to your max expire time for your longest job.